# McAfee Endpoint security Alert "Insufficient system resources" using cx_Oracle in Python:

Tags: python, windows, cx-oracle, mcafee

I am using Cx_oracle for a while in Python but I can not recently import cx_oracle in Python and got this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
```

In addition, I get McAfee security alert as shown below:

[image]

I reinstalled cx_oracle a few times and it has not worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is to use an older version of `cx_Oracle` using the following commands:

```
pip uninstall cx_Oracle
pip install -Iv cx_Oracle=="enter the version number here"
```

The reason is that McAfee might not integrate with the latest version of cx_Oracle or any other Python modules.

There are several other solutions including:

1. Uninstalling McAfee or any antivirus software that you have
2. Updating the drivers
3. Scanning the disk drivers to solve the issue
4. Modify the registry